# SQL Server 2012: Select serialized data

Tags: sql-server, string, serialization, nvarchar

I have some columns nvarchar type containing serialized strings. Query

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

returns all data but serialized strings are empty. Do you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: Looks like your serialization process failed :)

Comment: They are serialized with PHP function and I didn't try to unserialize them using SQL Server

Comment: They may be serialised in PHP but they weren't written to SQL Server. Quite obvious. SQL Server and other RDBMS do not randomly delete or change data...

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio returns this data well but when I try to make the same query from php script using ODBC then it returns empty strings instead of serialized strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in MS SQL Server Native Client 11.0 ODBC driver. It's resolved by using php_pdo_sqlsrv driver for connection, sqlsrv: ...